# Quectel M66 unable to input the data for HTTP POST

Tags: http, post, input, quectel

Quectell M66 doesn't let me input the data which I need to send to a LAMP Web Server through HTTP POST method. After entering the AT+QHTTPPOST=10,50 command Quectell outputs: CNNECT and it doesn't let me input the data at all  and after sometime gives +CME ERROR:3825 which is timeout error. My codes are:

```
AT+CGATT=1
AT+QIFGCNT=0
AT+QICSGP=1,"bsnlnet" 
AT+QIREGAPP
AT+QIACT
AT+QILOCIP
AT+QHTTPURL=66,30
my_66byte_long_URL
AT+QHTTPPOST=10,50
AT+QIDEACT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently, I had found the answer to my own problem and I am posting it here so that it could be of help to others.

[enter link description here](http://epos.lisha.ufsc.br/GSM+GPRS+Quectel+M95)